# recipe say's to sponge on 2 cups warm milk and 1 cup warm water, what does this mean?

Tags: mixing

Recipe from Great Grandma say's to sponge on 2 cups warm milk and 1 cup warm water. What does this mean?

Comment: A little more detail regarding the actual recipe would be helpful,

Comment: If I had to take a guess, you need to ... "sponge the milk and water" onto what ever product you are creating ;-), or use a pastry brush.

Comment: Some kind of basting technique, I gather.

Comment: What are you making? A cake, a meatloaf, something else? Without the whole recipe, it's almost impossible to recognize the meaning.

Comment: I'm going to put this on hold, because as people have pointed out, it's impossible to tell based on the information you've provided so far, and you've already gotten one answer assuming you're asking about bread, which sounds unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

> "A technique of mixing dough in a two stage process to produce more
>   flavorful loaves. The first stage involves mixing a small amount of
>   water, flour and yeast together first and giving it some time to
>   ferment. The sponge is then mixed in with the rest of the ingredient.
>
> Loaves produced this way requires shorter fermentation time, allow for
>   more flexibility in timing (the sponge can be held in the fridge for
>   longer time), develops a better flavor and requires less yeast."

(http://www.foodista.com/technique/CRDDPSTF/sponge-method#)

Also:

> A sponge ferment is usually a sticky process that uses part of the
>   flour, part or all of the water, and part or all of the yeast of a
>   total- or straight-dough formula. Highly liquid sponges of batter
>   consistencies are mixed with a whip, spoon, or fork. Lower hydration,
>   stiffer sponges are lightly mixed or kneaded just until the dough
>   begins to develop. The sponge is allowed to rest and ferment for a
>   period of time in an environment of a desired temperature and
>   humidity. When the sponge's fermentation time has elapsed or it has
>   reached a desired volumetric growth characteristic, the final dough's
>   ingredients are added.

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponge_and_dough)